# Python pymySQL string quotes

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I am trying to insert a string

```
insert_cmd = "INSERT INTO inv values (\""+str(row[1])+"\",\""+str(row[2])+"\")
(cur.execute(insert_cmd))
```

Error Message:

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'google search appliance"","active","D\' at line 1')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to use query parameters to avoid quoting and other issues:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO inv values (%s, %s)", (str(row[1]), str(row[2])))
```

It's also a best practice to name your columns in case your model changes later:

```
"INSERT INTO inv (col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s)"
```

Comment: In fact the above is the ONLY way you should be doing this. Or you run the risk of SQL injection.